How to highlight/visualize polylines one by one in a layer in ArcGIS Pro
I have a set of polylines as a layer in ArcGIS Pro in a table layer. I can highlight/visualize each polyline by clicking on the side of each row in the table. It is a time consuming process. I tried to automate this using python code in python code in a way that the code iterate through each row. Code still highlights the last polyline when code run is complete. I want it to highlight all polylines one by one. I introduce time function to delay the process but it does not work either. Here is the code below.
import time  # Import the time module to add a delay

# Access the current ArcGIS Pro project and map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mp = aprx.activeMap

# Specify the layer name and retrieve the layer object
layer_name = "Tracks_Polylines"
layer = mp.listLayers(layer_name)[0]

# Get a list of all unique TrackID values in the layer
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, ["TrackID"]) as cursor:
    track_ids = sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})  # Use a set to get unique TrackIDs

# Loop through each TrackID and perform selection with a delay
for track_id in track_ids:
    where_clause = f"TrackID = {track_id}"
    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(layer, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
    
    # print the current TrackID
    print(f"Highlighting TrackID: {track_id}")
    
    # Refresh the map view to ensure the selection is visible
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    
    # Pause for a few seconds before moving to the next TrackID
    time.sleep(2)  # Adjust the duration as needed (2 seconds in this case)

# Clear the selection after processing all TrackIDs
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(layer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")


It's unclear why you want to do this and personally I think you are going down the wrong road with your coding route. That said if you want to show features turn on/off one after another then you could "abuse" the range property of a feature layer.
So using a polygon dataset I had created and uniquely numbered I set the layers range properties as shown below. 25 comes from there being 25 rows in the featureclass.

You now have a range tab in the ribbon and I set min and max to be both 1 as shown below and active the range.

Finally click on the play button and you get this...

Zero coding!

Great :-). Yes it requires 0 coding. The only issue I am having now that it shows the value inside "Steps Interval" as 4. I would like to set it to 1 but it changes back to 4. Any suggestion.

Set min/max to 1 in current  range, see video.
